# ShinyProxy and authentication with IdentityServer4

Tags: r, shiny, identityserver4, shinyproxy

My ShinyProxy is up and running. If I use the authentication basic, it is working. I wanted to connect the ShinyProxy with my IdentityServer4.

Follow the [documentation of ShinyProxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#openid-connect-oidc), I configure my ShintProxy as follow:

```
proxy:
  title: Open Analytics Shiny Proxy
  port: 8080

  authentication: openid
  admin-groups: scientists
  openid:
    auth-url: https://myidentityserver4/connect/authorize
    token-url: https://myidentityserver4/connect/token
    jwks-url: https://myidentityserver4/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks
    client-id: ShinyProxy
    client-secret: password
```

When the user opens the browser to the ShinyApp, it is redirected to login page to the IdentityServer4. The user can login and then it is redirected to

> http://myshinyproxyurl)/login/oauth2/code/shinyproxy

Unfortunately, the result is

[image]

or if I try on my laptop the error is slightly different

[image]

It seems there are too many redirections in the ShinyProxy.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research and study, I found how to implement `Identity Server` with ShinyProxy. I have created a complete step-by-step guide in [my blog](https://www.puresourcecode.com/programming-languages/r/authentication-in-shinyproxy-with-identityserver/).

I hope it could help other guys.